# Проверка на содержание слова в url

Tags: javascript

У меня есть две ссылки на страницы, на одной из которых надо показать картинку, а на другой наоборот не показывать.

```
http://test_url/products - показать изображение.
http://test_url/product - не показывать.
```

Проверяю вот таким условием:

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/product') === -1) {
      $('.img').show();     
   }
```

В этом условии если индекс строки `'/product'` равен -1, то картинку я не показываю. Но как в этом условии показать изображение если урл содержит `/products`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/product') === -1 || 
  window.location.pathname.indexOf('/products') != -1) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратите условие

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/products') !== -1) {
  $('.img').show();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно регуляркой. [Это ***значительно*** медленнее чем `indexOf()`](https://jsperf.com/so-813830), но как еще один возможный вариант (и как предостережение не использовать его) - думаю, стоит упомянуть.

```js
const arr = [ 'http://test_url/product', 'http://test_url/products', 'http://test_url/product?foo', 'http://test_url/product/?bar', 'http://test_url/products/?baz'];

for (let show, i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  show = (/\/products(?:$|[/?])/i).test(arr[i]);  // или, что еще ужаснее, = !!arr[i].match(/\/product(s)?(?:$|[/?])/i)[1]
  console.log(`${arr[i]} - ${show ? 'показывать' : 'не показывать'}`);
}
```